# accessing invisible popup in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

in a interview they have asked below questions please tell me code or approach ...
1-how to access invisible popup.in selenium alert pop can be accessible using alert.accept() but if alert popup is invisible then how can we use.
2-code for automatic image display slider,some image slider has next and previous button we have to click next or previous so please let me know how to develop it in both way by clicking next button on image or automatic image display slider

i am using selenium web driver,java,Firefox
thanks a lot

Comment: Could you describe your question with a bit more details, maybe adding some examples also, showing what you mean exactly?

Comment: thanks skandigraun ,have a look to above questions once again...the interviewer asked these questions they have not given any example

Answer (score 0):

For the 1st question, AssertEquals will help us to go through invisible pop-ups and for the second one, I am not sure that they have asked the slider next or previous button will be on image....if it is outside image, then we can verify that if its present than click on particular id else not.

Comment: if its inside the image also, we can provide the Xpath by class or id , and response accordingly

Comment: thanks a lot  Fazz..but how i know that there is a invisible popups  or not could you provide some  sample code if possible